# Is there a way to create a dynamic bell curve in Excel?

Tags: excel, graphing

I have a report that is generated weekly with productivity numbers for employees in Excel.  I am wanting to create a bell curve for several data points where the viewer can select the week time range and the bell curve will be updated.  I have figured out formula wise how to make the mean, standard deviation, norm.dist, etc update when the date range is updated.  The issue I have yet to solve or find an answer to though is how to graph this data without having to manually update the ranges of the graphs.  Once this is accomplished I'd also like to be able to add vertical lines for the average and 1 standard deviation on either side of the average.  Is this a possibility in Excel or any other program?  I was hoping to be able to use Excel, but am happy to explore other options if that's the only way to do it.  Thanks!

Comment: Making the graph is easy - you just plot all the productivity numbers and they should look like a bell if they are a standard distribution.  So then the only thing to do is make the vertical lines at the mean and each standard deviation.  How I usually do lines is overlay the data chart with a second "100% stacked column" chart that has the same x-axis but the number 1 for the y-axis (so you need a helper column in your data).  I will try to make an example

Comment: Can we please have the names of the headers of your data?  And info on which of them is the x-axis and y-axis of the chart.

Comment: Make the data dynamic then plot that, use another chart overlaid with + and minus 1 sigma .

Comment: Here is an example that shows how I would do something similar: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p8UvDj3s-B6tgXv6RUjo_-qs60V9c0Qb/export?format=xlsx